# Use constant declared in Initializer in Environment.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, constants

Essentially what I want to do is keep my email username and password in a separate file to my environment.rb I've used the initializers in other places to do this - but here the environment seems to be loaded first:

**development.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.example.com",
    :port => 587,
    :domain => "www.example.com",
    :authentication => "plain",
    :user_name => SMTP_USERNAME,
    :password => SMTP_PASSWORD,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
 }
```

When I start my Rails server I get an error:

```
uncaught exception: uninitialized constant SMTP_USERNAME
```

Would this be a scoping issue of due to the fact that the constants in the Initializers are declared after the environment, and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

What if you try defining your constants in `application.rb`, inside `class Application < Rails::Application`? You might then access the constants by doing something like `Application::SMTP_USERNAME`. That's just a guess.

Comment: The reason I put them in a separate file is that I don't want the username and password committed to my git repository.

Comment: Gotcha. Might it make sense to define these constants in a separate config file that you tell Git to ignore, and then include that file in, say, `application.rb` (since `environment.rb` seems not to do the trick)?

Comment: It's true that if I load the initializer file in environment.rb it works, but my production server is on Heroku where I'll be using evironment variables so I don't really want to force the load. However, thanks this works for now!

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to load the separate config file in production? You could always wrap the include in `if Rails.env != 'production'`. I might be misunderstanding, though.

Comment: I also get warnings on starting my server "warning: already initialized constant SMTP_USERNAME", I guess this means the initializer files are compiled after the environment is set up. I can't be the first person who doesn't want to include passwords in my environment.rb?!

Comment: Yeah, I don't know. You could probably solve that particular problem, though, by doing `SMTP_USERNAME ||= "foo"` instead of `SMTP_USERNAME = "foo"`.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190473/hiding-my-sensitive-information-e-g-password-from-github

Comment: Again the problem is that the config.yml is loaded in the initilizers :(