# How to hide personal data in Python script

Tags: python, git

I need to push `Python` script to `Git` repo. Script contains variables with personal data like `USER_NAME = "some_name"` and `USER_PASS = "some_password"`. This data could be accessible for other users. I want to hide this data.

I found following approach:

- create separate `data.py` module with `USER_NAME = "some_name"` and `USER_PASS = "some_password"`
- import it once to generate compiled version- `data.pyc`
- change main script source: variables should be accessible like

  `import data`

  `username = data.USER_NAME`

  `password = data.USER_PASS`
- remove `data.py`and push `data.pyc` to repo

This was promising, but actually data in `data.pyc` appears like `???some_namet???some_passwords???` and still could be recognized as username and password.

So what is the best practices to hide data in `Python` script?

Comment: What do you mean by other users? Are you talking about people running the script or people who will be working on the script also?

Comment: Yes, persons who also have access to `Git` Project and work with this script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include in git repo code to read those things from environment variables.  On the target machine, set those environment variables.  This could be done by hand, or with a script that you don't include in your repo.  Include instructions in your readme file

Answer (score 1):

Try using an YAML file and not pushing it to your repo, like from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190473/hiding-my-sensitive-information-e-g-password-from-github). You can use the python module `yaml` to read the data.

Comment: With YAML, make sure you use `safe_load` to avoid trying to deserialize and being insecure.

Answer (score 1):

You should never put sensitive pieces of information inside your code neither store them into a public repository.

It's better to follow Joel Goldstick's suggestion and modify your code to get passwords from private sources, e.g. local environment variables or local modules.

Try googling for *"python store sensitive information"* to look at some ideas (and involved issues).